# How to count errors with jQuery validation inside collapses of a form separately and show the number of errors in the header of every collapse?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

This is code jQuery that show the number of all errors in the form , but i want the number of errors in every collapse separately.i want to show the number of errors on the header of every collapse .but the problem that it gives me the numbers of all errors in the form

```
var $registerForm = $("#"+$nameForm).validate({

    ignore: false,
    errorClass: errorClass,
    errorElement: errorElement,
    highlight: function(element) {
          $(element).parent().removeClass('state-success').addClass("state-error");
          $(element).removeClass('valid');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
          $(element).parent().removeClass("state-error").addClass('state-success');
          $(element).addClass('valid');
    },

    // Rules for form validation
    rules: {
          username: {
               required: true
          },
          email: {
              required: true,
              email: true
          },
          password: {
              required: true,
              minlength: 3,
              maxlength: 20
          },
          passwordConfirm: {
              required: true,
              minlength: 3,
              maxlength: 20,
              equalTo: '#password'
          },
          firstname: {
              required: true
          },
          lastname: {
              required: true
          },
          gender: {
              required: true
          },
          terms: {
              required: true
          }
      },

      // Messages for form validation
      messages: {
           login: {
                required: 'Please enter your login'
           },
           email: {
                required: 'Please enter your email address',
                email: 'Please enter a VALID email address'
           },
           password: {
                required: 'Please enter your password'
           },
           passwordConfirm: {
                required: 'Please enter your password one more time',
                equalTo: 'Please enter the same password as above'
           },
           firstname: {
                required: 'Please select your first name'
           },
           lastname: {
                required: 'Please select your last name'
           },
           gender: {
                required: 'Please select your gender'
           },
           terms: {
                required: 'You must agree with Terms and Conditions'
           }
       },

       invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
                // 'this' refers to the form
                var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
                if (errors) {
                   var message = errors == 1 ? '1 erreur' : errors + ' erreurs';
                   $("#bdg").show();
                   $("#bdg").html(message);
                 } else {
                   $("#bdg").hide();
                 }
        },

        // Do not change code below
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
             error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        }
    });
  }

  $counter++;
});


form.delivreLe :délivré le
attr :atribut
```